# How to publish an update of an Apple app after successfully testing it in Testflight?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Is it necessary to first expire the build in Testflight before I can publish it to the Apple Store? I can't find the answer on the Apple Dev pages.

Comment: No, simply create a release under the "App Store" tab for your app in itunes connect and add the build so that you can submit it for review.

Comment: Do I have to do this when I already have a version in the App Store that has been approved before? I just want to publish an updated version of the app.

Comment: You need to create a new version on the left side of the screen and then upload a build with a version number that matches your new version.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not necessary. Just fill out your app info and submit it.